# Tumblr : images are overflowing some specific posts

Tags: html, css

I found a new Tumblr theme recently that I love (nvye.tumblr.com). The problem is that, with a particular kind of post, when there's a text and an image, the image overflows the post. 
I tried to look in my HTML code but I couldn't find anything (I am a coding noob).

It looks like this

[image]

[image: Image 2]

The problem is that it's really rare, and happens only with one type of post, but I don't know what it is. In the Tumblr code, there is a list with all the type of posts (i.e 'Post', 'Text', 'Quote', 'Photoset' ...) but I can't tell which one it is.

So here's the code :

```html
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"><!--mce:0--></script>
<script src="toggle.js" type="text/javascript"><!--mce:1--></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".description").hide();
$(".about").click(function(){
$('.description').slideToggle("fast");
return true;
});
});
</script>

<meta name="color:Background" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="color:Text" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="color:Links" content="#dad8d8"/>
<meta name="color:Hover" content="#666666"/>
<meta name="color:Scrollbar" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:Answer" content="#ebebeb"/>
<meta name="color:Answer Border" content="#dad8d8"/>
<meta name="color:Drop Down Menu" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:Posts" content="#FFFFFF"/>
<meta name="color:Borders" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:Sidebar" content="#eeeeee"/>
<meta name="color:Sidebar Border" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:Icon" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="color:Icon Border" content="#FFFFFF"/>
<meta name="color:Drop Down Menu Text" content="#FFFFFF"/>
<meta name="color:Notes Page" content="#000000"/>

<meta name="image:Background" content=""/>
<meta name="image:Sidebar Background" content="http://static.tumblr.com/ykziu7r/vDnn9wdl4/tumblr_n5akoi6yso1qin2xoo1_1280.jpg"/>
<meta name="image:Post Background Image" content="http://static.tumblr.com/ykziu7r/TRdn9wdlm/tumblr_n5ako8i7654redfghuoi6yso1qin2xoo1_1280_opt.jpg"/>

<meta name="text:First custom link title" content=""/>
<meta name="text:First custom link url" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Second custom link title" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Second custom link url" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Third custom link title" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Third custom link url" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Fourth custom link title" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Fourth custom link url" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Fifth custom link title" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Fifth custom link url" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Sixth custom link title" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Sixth custom link url" content=""/>
<meta name="text:Drop Down Title" content="Links"/>
<meta name="text:Sidebar Margin" content="100"/>

<meta name="if:First custom link" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Second custom link" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Third custom link" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Fourth custom link" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Fifth custom link" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Sixth custom link" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Submit link" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Archive link" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Home link" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Message link" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Show Icon" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Small Icon" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Medium Icon" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Large Icon" content="0"/>
<meta name="if:Inverted Fade" content="1" />
<meta name="if:Faded Images" content="0" />
<meta name="if:Cross cursor" content="1"/>

<meta name="font:Body" content="Courier New"/>

<title>{Title}</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">

{block:Description}
<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />
{/block:Description}

<style type="text/css">
{CustomCSS}

p{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#tumblr_controls{
position:absolute;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;
z-index:99999;
}

#tumblr_controls{
position:fixed !important;
}

#tumblr_controls{
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
opacity: 0.6;
}
#tumblr_controls:hover{
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
opacity: 1;
}

a{
text-decoration: none;
color:{color:links};
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
{block:ifcrosscursor}
cursor: crosshair;
{/block:ifcrosscursor}
}

a:hover{
color:{color:hover};
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
{block:ifcrosscursor}
cursor: crosshair;
{/block:ifcrosscursor}
}

body{
color:{color:Text};
background-color:{color:Background};
background-image:url({image:Background});
background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: repeat;
font-size:10px;
line-height:10px;
text-align: center;
font-family: {font:Body};
overflow-x:hidden;
{block:ifcrosscursor}
cursor: crosshair;
{/block:ifcrosscursor}
}

#content{
margin: auto auto auto auto ;
width:100%;
top:0px;
position:relative;
}

#content .posts{
width:620px;
font-family: {font:Body};
margin: 25px 0px 0px 30px;
margin-left: 1%;
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:500px;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
{block:ifcrosscursor}
cursor: crosshair;
{/block:ifcrosscursor}
}

#content .entry{
{block:IndexPage}
width:250px;
margin:15px;
background-color:{Color:Posts};
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:{color:Borders};
padding:10px 10px 8px 10px;
{block:ifcrosscursor}
cursor: crosshair;
{/block:ifcrosscursor}
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:460px;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top:0px;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
}

#content .entry img{
{block:IndexPage}
max-width:250px;
{block:ifroundedimages}
-webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
{/block:ifroundedimages}
{/block:IndexPage}
}

.entry:hover .tc {
opacity: .5;
filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
margin-left: 0;
}

.entry .permaone {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
text-align: left;
bottom:11px;
left:10px;
opacity: 0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
z-index: 10000;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
font-size: 10px;
height: 14px;
line-height: 14px;
font-family: {font:Permalink};
text-transform: Uppercase;
color:#000000;
padding: 3px;
-webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}

.entry:hover .permaone{
opacity: 1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.permaone:hover{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);
}

.permaone a{
color:#000;
-webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}

.permaone a:hover{
color:{color:hover};
-webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}

.entry:hover .tc {
opacity: .5;
filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
margin-left: 0;
}

.entry .permatwo {
position: absolute;
width: 244px;
width: auto;
bottom:33px;
left:10px;
opacity: 0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
z-index: 10000;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
font-size: 10px;
height: 14px;
line-height: 14px;
font-family: {font:Permalink};
text-transform: Uppercase;
color:#000000;
padding: 3px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.entry:hover .permatwo{
opacity: 1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.permatwo:hover{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);
}

.permatwo a{
color:#000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.permatwo a:hover{
color:{color:hover};
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.entry:hover .tc {
opacity: .5;
filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
margin-left: 0;
}

.entry .permathree {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
text-align: left;
bottom:55px;
left:10px;
opacity: 0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
z-index: 10000;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
font-size: 10px;
height: 14px;
line-height: 14px;
font-family: {font:Permalink};
text-transform: Uppercase;
color:#000000;
padding: 3px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.entry:hover .permathree{
opacity: 1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.permathree:hover{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);
}

.permathree a{
color:#000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.permathree a:hover{
color:{color:hover};
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.entry:hover .tc {
opacity: .5;
filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
margin-left: 0;
}

.entry .permafour {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
text-align: left;
bottom:77px;
left:10px;
opacity: 0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
z-index: 10000;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.70);
font-size: 10px;
height: 14px;
line-height: 14px;
font-family: {font:Permalink};
text-transform: Uppercase;
color:#000000;
padding: 3px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.entry:hover .permafour{
opacity: 1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.permafour:hover{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);
}

.permafour a{
color:#000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.permafour a:hover{
color:{color:hover};
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.top{
width:250px;
text-align:left;
z-index:5000;
position: fixed;
font-size:11px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-top:{text:Sidebar Margin}px;
top:0px;
left:52%;
height:100%;
border-left-style:solid;
border-right-style:solid;
border-width:10px;
border-color:{color:Sidebar Border};
background-color:{color:Sidebar};
background-image:url({image:Sidebar Background});
background-attachment: fixed; no-repeat;
{block:ifcrosscursor}
cursor: crosshair;
{/block:ifcrosscursor}
}

{block:IndexPage}
{block:ifinvertedfade}
img{
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
opacity: 1;
}
img:hover{
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
opacity: 0.7;
}
{/block:ifinvertedfade}

{block:iffadedimages}
img{
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
opacity: 0.8;
}
img:hover{
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
opacity: 1;
}
{/block:iffadedimages}
{/block:IndexPage}

.h1{
display:block;
font-size:27px;
line-height:20px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-family: {font:Body};
}

.h2{
font-size:22px;
line-height:22px;
margin-bottom:0px;
font-family: {font:Body};
display:block;
text-align:center;
}

#h3{
font-size:26px;
line-height:26px;
margin-bottom:5px;
text-align:center;
width:238px;
padding:4px;
}

.h7{
width:512px;
font-size:{text:Body Font Size}px;
line-height:{text:Body Font Size}px;
font-family: {font:Body};
}

.nav{
text-align:center;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
font-family: {font:Body};
}

.notes{
width:614px;
padding-left:0px;
text-align:left;
background-color:{color:Notes Page};
}

{block:IndexPage}
.textperma{
font-family:{font:Body};
font-size:10px;
line-height:10px;
text-align:right;
opacity: 0.0;
margin-top:7px;
margin-bottom:2px;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.7s;
}

.entry:hover .textperma{
opacity:1;
padding-top:0px;
}
{/block:IndexPage}

.quote{
font-size:25px;
line-height:35px;
text-transform:none;
margin-bottom:5px;
font-family: {font:Body};
}

.audio{
{block:IndexPage}
width:240px;
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:604px;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
background-color:#000;
padding:5px;
margin-top:-2px;
margin-bottom:1px;
}

.audiocap, .videocap{
display:block;
padding:0px;
}

.albumart, .albumart img{
{block:IndexPage}
width:250px;
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:614px;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
}

div.video embed,
div.post div.video object {
{block:IndexPage}
width:250px !important;
height:150px !important;
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:500px !important;
height:400px !important;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
}

.question{
margin-bottom:5px;
font-size:10px;
line-height:10px;
display:block;
font-family: {font:Body};
background-color:{color:Answer};
padding:5px;
}

.asker{
font-family: {font:Body};
font-size:10px;
line-height:10px;
}

.answer{
padding:3px;
font-size:10px;
line-height:10px;
font-family: {font:Body};
color: {color:text};
}

#link{
width:580px;
height:auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:0px;
padding:18px 17px 18px 17px;
background-color:{color:Notes Page};
}

#chat{
width:580px;
height:auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:0px;
padding:18px 17px 18px 17px;
background-color:{color:Notes Page};
}

#quot{
width:564px;
height:auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:0px;
padding:22px 25px 22px 25px;
background-color:{color:Notes Page};
}

#text{
width:580px;
height:auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:0px;
padding:18px 17px 18px 17px;
background-color:{color:Notes Page};
}

#vidvid{
width:580px;
height:auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:0px;
padding:18px 17px 18px 17px;
background-color:{color:Notes Page};
}

#photoset{
width:580px;
height:auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:0px;
padding:18px 17px 18px 17px;
background-color:{color:Notes Page};
}

#ans{
width:580px;
height:auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:0px;
padding:18px 17px 18px 17px;
background-color:{color:Notes Page};
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
background-color:{color:Scrollbar};
height:100px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
background-color:{color:Scrollbar};
height:10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
height:10px;
width:8px;
background-color:{color:Background};
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/imovwvl/dJWl20ley/jqueryformasonry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/imovwvl/rSGl20lfv/masonry.js">
</script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/df28qmy/SHUlh3i7s/jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/thpaaos/lLwkowcqm/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function () {
$('.posts').masonry(),
$('.masonryWrap').infinitescroll({
navSelector : "div#navigation",
// selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
nextSelector : "div#navigation a#nextPage",
// selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : ".entry",
// selector for all items you'll retrieve
bufferPx : 10000,
extraScrollPx: 11000,
loadingImg : "",
loadingText : "<em></em>",
},
// call masonry as a callback.
function() { $('.posts').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) }); }
);
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(window).load(function(){$("p").remove(":contains('Source:')");});</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="top">
<div align="center">
<span class="h7">

<a href="/"><div style="font-size:30px;">{Title}</div></a>

{block:ifshowicon}
<br><br><a href="/"><img src="{PortraitURL-128}"
{block:ifsmallicon}width="64px"{/block:ifsmallicon}
{block:ifmediumicon}width="96px"{/block:ifmediumicon}
{block:iflargeicon}width="128px"{/block:iflargeicon}
target="_blank" style="padding:5px; background-color:{color:Icon}; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-radius:99px; border-color:{color:Icon Border};"></a>{/block:ifshowicon}
<br><br>
<div align="center"><div id="h4">{Description}<br><br>

<a href="http://nvye.tumblr.com/tags"><div style="font-size:20px;">MY TAGS</a></div>

</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>

<div id="content">
<div class="posts">
{block:Posts}
<div class="entry">

{block:Text}
{block:IndexPage}
{block:Title}<span class="h1">{Title}</span>{/block:Title}
{Body}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="textperma"><a href="{Permalink}">
{NoteCount}</a> / <a href="{ReblogURL}">REBLOG</a></a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}<div style="margin-left:0px;"</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:PermalinkPage}<div id="text">{block:Title}<span class="h1">{Title}</span>{/block:Title}{Body}</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}{/block:Text}

{block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}
<b><div class="permaone"><a href="{Permalink}"><a href="{Permalink}">Permalink</a> ∞ <a href="{ReblogURL}">Reblog</a></div><div class="permatwo"><a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a></div><div class="permathree"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a></div><div class="permafour"><a href="{Permalink}">{24HourWithZero}:{Minutes}</a></div></b><a href="{Permalink}" target="_blank"><img src="{PhotoURL-400}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="450"/>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
{LinkOpenTag}
<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="614"/></a>
{LinkCloseTag}
{/block:permalinkpage}
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage}
<b><div class="permaone"><a href="{Permalink}"><a href="{Permalink}">Permalink</a> ∞ <a href="{ReblogURL}">Reblog</a></div><div class="permatwo"><a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a></div><div class="permathree"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a></div><div class="permafour"><a href="{Permalink}">{24HourWithZero}:{Minutes}</a></div></b>
{Photoset-250}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}<div style="margin-left:0px;"</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:PermalinkPage}<div id="photoset">{Photoset-500}</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photoset}

{block:Quote}
{block:IndexPage}<div class="quote">"{Quote}" <small><i>{block:Source}&nbsp;- {Source}{/block:Source}</small></i></div>{/block:IndexPage}{block:IndexPage}
<div class="textperma"><a href="{Permalink}">
{NoteCount}</a> / <a href="{ReblogURL}">REBLOG</a></a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}<div style="margin-left:0px;"</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:PermalinkPage}<div id="quot"><div class="quote">"{Quote}" <small><i>{block:Source}&nbsp;- {Source}{/block:Source}</small></i></div></div>{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Quote}

{block:Link}
{block:IndexPage}<a href="{URL}"{Target}><span class="h2">+ {Name}</span></a>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}{/block:IndexPage}{block:IndexPage}
<div class="textperma"><a href="{Permalink}">
{NoteCount}</a> / <a href="{ReblogURL}">REBLOG</a></a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}<div style="margin-left:0px;"</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:PermalinkPage}
<div id="link"><a href="{URL}"{Target}><span class="h2"> +{Name}</span></a>
{block:Description}<small>{Description}</small>{/block:Description}</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Link}

{block:Video}
<div class="video">
{block:IndexPage}<span class="h2"><a href="{permalink}">VIDEO POST ►</span></a></div>{/block:IndexPage}</span>
{block:PermalinkPage}
<div id="vidvid">{VideoEmbed-500}</div>
{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Video}

{block:Chat}
{block:IndexPage}{block:Title}<div class="ptitle">{Title}</div>
{/block:Title}{block:Lines}{block:Label}<b>{Label}</b> {/block:Label}{Line}<br>{/block:Lines}{/block:IndexPage}{block:IndexPage}
<div class="textperma"><a href="{Permalink}">
{NoteCount}</a> / <a href="{ReblogURL}">REBLOG</a></a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}<div style="margin-left:0px;"</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:PermalinkPage}<div id="chat">{block:Title}<div class="ptitle">{Title}</div>{/block:Title}{block:Lines}{block:Label}<b>{Label}</b> {/block:Label}{Line}<br>{/block:Lines}</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Chat}

{block:Audio}
<a href="{Permalink}">
{block:AlbumArt}<div class="albumart"><img src="{AlbumArtURL}"></a></div>{/block:AlbumArt}</a><div class="audio">{AudioPlayerBlack}</div>
{block:PermalinkPage}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Audio}

{block:Answer}
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="question">{Asker} said:</a> {Question}</div>
<div class="answer"><i>{Answer}</i></div>{/block:IndexPage}
{block:IndexPage}
<div class="textperma"><a href="{Permalink}">
{NoteCount} NOTES</a></div>
{/block:IndexPage}{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}<div style="margin-left:0px;"</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:PermalinkPage}<div id="ans"><div class="question">{Asker} said:</a> {Question}</div>
<div class="answer"><i>{Answer}</i></div></div></div>{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Answer}

{block:PermalinkPage}<div class="notes">
{block:Caption}<br>{Caption}{/block:Caption}
Posted on {Month} {DayofMonth}{DayofMonthSuffix} at {12Hour}:{Minutes} {CapitalAMPM}
<br>Has a total of: {NoteCount} Notes
{block:PostNotes}<br><br><div style="text-align:left; margin-bottom:-1px; max-height: 200px; width:614px; background-color:{color:Notes Page}; overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">{PostNotes}</div>{/block:PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PermalinkPage}
</div>{/block:Posts}</div></div>

{block:IndexPage}
<div class="column navigation" id="navigation">
{block:Pagination}
{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}" class="navigate">{/block:PreviousPage}{block:PreviousPage}</a>{/block:PreviousPage}
{block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}" class="navigate" id="nextPage">{/block:NextPage}{block:NextPage}</a>{/block:NextPage}{/block:Pagination}
</div>
{/block:IndexPage}

<div style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;  opacity:0.8; position:fixed !important;z-index:-9999999999999999999999; width: 500px; height:100%;"><img src="{image:Post Background Image}"/></a></div>


</div></div></div></div></div>

</body></html></body>
```

I tried my best, but the issue is so specific and since I'm really bad at coding it's just so hard for me to find something ..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Your request is too broad and has far too much code. It will likely be voted down and closed

Comment: First thing I would try is to open up your page with Chrome, right click on the overflowing image and select "inspect". You should be able to check which type it is from that.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the theme creator forgot to change the blockquote margins. I tried inspecting and this fixed it:

```
<style type="text/css">blockquote { margin: 0; }</style>
```